# drag and drop to checkedlistbox

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I have a checkedlistbox and I want to drag and drop only image extensions and not text files.
so how do I get it done.
I am able to drag and drop all file formats but I need only image files.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CheckedListBox1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.DragDrop

    Dim Files As String() = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
    For Each FileName As String In Files
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(FileName, CheckState.Checked)
        Thumbcontrol1.AddThumbnail(FileName)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Couldn't you check the extensions of each `FileName`?

Comment: I know but how to add in the code is my question?

Comment: Just swap the two statements in the for loop.  So it doesn't get added when the image loading code falls over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check each file name's extension.

```
Private Shared ReadOnly SupportedExtensions As String() = {".jpg", ".jpeg", ".gif"}

Private Sub CheckedListBox1_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles CheckedListBox1.DragDrop
    Dim Files As String() = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
    For Each FileName As String In Files
        Dim Extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileName).ToLower
        If Array.IndexOf(SupportedExtensions, Extension) <> -1 Then
            CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(FileName, CheckState.Checked)
            Thumbcontrol1.AddThumbnail(FileName)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You may want to add similar code to the DragEnter method to show `DragDropEffects.None` if there are no picture files in the dragged file list.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response and you really saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (you'll need to add in more file extensions):

```
Dim Files As String() = CType(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
For Each FileName As String In Files
    If FileName.Contains(".jpg") Or FileName.Contains(".bmp") Then
       CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(FileName, CheckState.Checked)
       Thumbcontrol1.AddThumbnail(FileName)
    End If
Next
```

You will also need to account for the case of the filenames.